# Dimensional stability of tool steel when hardening

Tags: steel, machining

I am trying to figure out how to make dimensionally accurate cutters to use in a shaper. They should be suitable to cut part of a circle into 17-4 and 4150, the circular part cannot be turned on a lathe because there are parts that will be in the way. My understanding is that A2 and M2 are most suitable because they are machinable and have good dimensional stability. My question is how predictable are these types of steel when being heat treated? And will the expand uniformly in all 3 dimensions? Or will an arch shape become more arched or straighten?

I've done some math here with the Coefficients of Thermal Expansion on the tech data pages listed below and come to the conclusion that these tools steels should expand by about .0135" and .0118" per inch. Have I done this correctly?

https://hudsontoolsteel.com/technical-data/steelA2

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=7.91+*+%281700+*+%2810+%5E+-6%29%29

https://hudsontoolsteel.com/technical-data/steelM2

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=6.97+*+%281700+*+%2810+%5E+-6%29%29

Comment: Will they then shrink during the cooling part of the heat treatment? And by the same amount?

Comment: I'm trying to find out how the size will be affected by the whole heat treating process

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with coefficient of thermal expansion because the steel cools down afterwards. Dimensional changes after heat treatment are something else altogether. It's also different for different heat treatments. The actual calculations are something you would look in a book for rather than online. You mention a shaper...you can't grind afterwards? This is more detailed than I would expect to find online. Anything more, look to a book: https://vacaero.com/information-resources/the-heat-treat-doctor/1316-dimensional-changes-after-heat-treatment.html

Comment: Also, grain orientation seems to matter: https://www.productionmachining.com/articles/predicting-size-change-from-heat-treatment

Comment: Air hardened tool steel like A2 tends to be relatively stable, simply because it doesn't need to be cooled extremely quickly to harden.